# Is there a reason why string_view implementation uses pointer,size instead of pointer,pointer

Tags: c++, optimization, c++17

As you may know C++17 string view can be implemented either as a pair of 2 pointers(begin, end), or pointer(begin), and size.
I noticed in one implementation that it is implemented with pointer, size.

Is there a good reason why this was done, or was it just a coin-toss kind of a decision?

I wonder since vector implementations usually have 3 pointers, instead of pointer, size, size.

Only reasonable explanation I have is that .size() may be called more often than .end() so we optimize for that(end requires addition, but size is free from computation).

Comment: Have you benchmarked different approaches? Have you had discussions with other compiler engineers about this? There's probably a reason here. It's not the sort of thing you'd decide by a coin toss unless the difference really didn't matter.

Comment: A pointer and size lets you take old c-string functions and change them to using a `string_view` with the only change at the call site being `foo(ptr, size)` -> `foo({ptr, size})`

Comment: @NathanOliver It would be the same if string_view took pointer pointer.

Comment: @Justin Not at all.  If it took two pointers you need to change `foo(ptr, size)` -> `foo({ptr, ptr + size})` which is more typing.

Comment: Oh, there is no `string_view(char const*, char const*)` constructor. TIL.

Comment: @NathanOliver Question isn't about the interface of string_view, it's about the implementation.

Comment: std::vector and std::string need to store the capacity beside size so obviously there must be 3 fields

Comment: @phuclv Note that OP isn't questioning why 3 fields, OP is pointing out that those 3 fields are all pointers rather than a pointer and 2 sizes.

Comment: I just want to say that that I agree with @Barry and Justin replies.

Comment: It might be meaningle for default ``

Comment: it is amazing how this question got put on hold because it is "opinion based"... total nonsense, I would bet my monthly salary that if we could magically summon mclow, chandler or godbolt they would be able to give us a reason.

Comment: @Barry David Stone said that for vector implementations pointers  to size and capacity is ABI, and he said that size would be faster... so much for opinion based :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_RxfThlJ_0#t=13m6s